# Increase the number of Anchor points on a circle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

By default the circle has 4 anchor points. Is there a way to increase it?

Not manually adding them with the Add Anchor Point Tool with which you could never possibly manage the natural symmetry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your circle and then go to

`Object > Path > Add Anchor Points`

Repeat as desired.

New points are added midway between existing points.

Comment: well yes, kindof. if i leave the part about beziers not being round. what if you want 5 points :)

Comment: @joojaa If you want 5, other strategies can be used. I think @scott’s method is the best way to go for most cases where you need more anchor points.

Comment: @joolaa, if you want to add 5 equidistant anchor points, draw a pentagon (using the Polygon tool) over the circle, turn it into a guide. Use the guide to add anchor the points using the Add Anchor Point tool.

Answer (score 0):

draw your circle, run the Ovalize script below, specify the number of anchors

http://shspage.com/aijs/en/

Answer (score 0):

Polar grid tool may be what you are looking for, found within the line segment tool sub menu, at the bottom (CS 5.1). Double click and specify precisely. Best of luck :+>